# Adding elements of a bash array

Tags: bash

I want to add the elements of a bash array together.  I provide an example.

```
invalv=(1 1 1 1 1)
nval=5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 nval=0
 invalv=(1 1 1 1 0)
 for i in "${invalv[@]}"; do (( nval+=i )); done
 printf '%s\n' "nval: $nval"
```